# For loop from file with multiple columns-BASH

Tags: bash

i have following text file (output.txt)

```
TECH-746 TECH 10400
TECH-747 TECH 10400
```

i need to read all columns and pass it to 3 variables and then submit it to curl command. While read simple won't work with curl (don't know why) so i need to use `for loop` (it works with curl), can i use one for loop or need to nest multiple ones

```
for project in `cat output.txt`; do
echo $project
curl -D- -u user:pass -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"TECH\"},\"parent\":{\"key\":\"$project\"},\"summary\":\"test",\"description\":\"test.\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Sub-task\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --silent https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/ >/dev/null
```

code above works, so i just want to "extend" to to include all other columns in file

Comment: If you had all three columns, where would column 2 and column 3 go in your curl command?  Or would they be ignored, and you would only use column 1?

Comment: You should strongly consider using `jq` (or something similar) to create your JSON rather than relying on shell interpolation.

Comment: @chepner, i can't use jq because having difficulties getting issues with subtasks (created python script which created output.txt)

Comment: @Milister I'm not sure what you mean. `curl ... --data "$(jq --arg p "$project" '{key: $p}')"` is an example of what I am talking about. This ensures the value of `$project` is encoded properly to form a valid JSON string.

Comment: @chepner it works now, solution provided by Jeff Breander works, mistakenly posted wrong code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while read` can pull a line into distinct variables.

```
while read project col2 col3
do
  curl -D- -u user:pass -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"TECH\"},\"parent\":{\"key\":\"$project\"},\"summary\":\"test",\"description\":\"test.\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Sub-task\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --silent https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/ >/dev/null
done < sourcefile.txt
```

EDIT:
The `curl` command also misses escaping one quote, compare the two lines below, the first one is the original, the second one is the one I've corrected.

```
curl -D- -u user:pass -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"TECH\"},\"parent\":{\"key\":\"$project\"},\"summary\":\"test",\"description\":\"test.\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Sub-task\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --silent https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/ >/dev/null
curl -D- -u user:pass -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"TECH\"},\"parent\":{\"key\":\"$project\"},\"summary\":\"test\",\"description\":\"test.\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Sub-task\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --silent https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/ >/dev/null
```

Comment: thanks, yes i know, but while simple won't pass values to curl, that's why i need to use for loop

Comment: @Milister then there's a problem with how you wrote your curl or your while loop. `while` doesn't inherently block `curl` commands.

Comment: Then can yo u please edit your question to provide a better example of what you want to achieve with your sample input?  Which specific curl command do you want to build with that input?

Comment: @JeffBreadner it works, it seems missing escaping quote did the trick !! Thanks